# iPod Touch (5th gen) 'Source type 1 not available' crash when using UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipod-touch

The iPod Touch (5th gen) has both a front and rear camera so why does my app crash when i try to present a UIImagePickerController with sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera

```
- (void)openImagePickerType:(NSString *)type
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    if([type isEqualToString:kImagePickerCameraString])
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    if([type isEqualToString:kImagePickerLibraryString])
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

    if(IS_IPAD && imagePicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary){
        DLog(@"show popopver image picker");


        UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
        [popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.cameraButton.bounds inView:self.cameraButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        self.popover = popover;

    }else{
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }


}
```

Comment: Does your app have access to the camera? You might have (accidentally) denied it when the popup asking for permission showed up.

Comment: good point, I dont know for sure, because its not my device, just the crash reports I'm getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, You should always validate if the resource is available or not, try using:

```
if(IS_IPAD && imagePicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary){

  if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
    // present the popover
  }

  else {
    // HEY, YOU CAN'T USE THIS
  }

}
```

From the [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImagePickerController/isSourceTypeAvailable:):

> Because a media source may not be present or may be unavailable,
>   devices may not always support all source types. For example, if you
>   attempt to pick an image from the user’s library and the library is
>   empty, this method returns false. Similarly, if the camera is already
>   in use, this method returns false.
>
> Before attempting to use an UIImagePickerController object to pick an
>   image, you must call this method to ensure that the desired source
>   type is available.

Second, I don't see clearly when this part should be executed:

```
else {
  [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

You should specify something like this:

```
if(IS_IPAD && imagePicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary){

  if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
    // present the popover
  }
  else {
    // HEY, YOU CAN'T USE THIS
  }

else if (imagePicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {

  if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    // present the popover
  }
  else {
    // HEY, YOU CAN'T USE THIS
  }

  ...

}
```

3. Why use an NSString type for `type var` when you can always use directly `UIImagePickerControllerSourceType` as you var's type

Comment: So under what circumstances does an iPod Touch NOT have the sourceType of UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera available?

Comment: I've updated my answer, basically the source type (in this case the camera) could not be available if the camera is broken, already being used by another app or the camera isn't ready for any other reason.